# Scanning directory and creating thumbnails from already exisiting images

Tags: php, image

What I'm trying to accomplish with this code is, first it scans a directory after images, then it takes one image and create a thumbnail out of it if its bigger than 170x170. The problem I'm having is when I try to load the new file it doesn't work quite as expected.

```
<?php
foreach (glob('img/*.png') as $f) {
    $list[filemtime($f) . '-' . $f] = $f;
}   

$keys = array_keys($list);      
sort($keys);

$picOne = $list[array_pop($keys)];
$picTwo = $list[array_pop($keys)];
$picThree = $list[array_pop($keys)];
$picFour = $list[array_pop($keys)];

list($width, $height) = getimagesize($picOne);
if ($width > 170 && $height > 170) {
    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor(170, 170);
    $source = imagecreatefrompng($picOne);
    imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, 170, 170, $width, $height);
    $path = $picOne."_170x170.png";
    imagepng($thumb, $path);
}

echo '<a href="'.$picOne.'" /><img width=170 height=170 src="'.$picOne.'" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;'; 
echo '<a href="'.$picTwo.'" /><img width=170 height=170 src="'.$picTwo.'" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;'; 
echo '<a href="'.$picThree.'" /><img width=170 height=170 src="'.$picThree.'" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;';  
echo '<a href="'.$picFour.'" /><img width=170 height=170 src="'.$picFour.'" /></a>';   

?>
```

This code should make a new file, right?

```
$path = $picOne."_170x170.png";
imagepng($thumb, $path)
```

That part works fine sure but $picOne gets _170x170.png added to it and I don't understand why. What I think I've done is just to create a new file with the $picOne name + _170x170.png but instead $picOne gets it as well.

Can anyone help me fix this code or explain what I need to do to get it to work?

Here's what I'm trying to do basically:
1. Scan a directory.
2. Take an image and create a thumbnail from it.
3. Output the thumbnail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having issue is that you are not creating new file but overwriting existing file. To create new file every time you try using this loop :

```
    $path =  $picOne."_170x170.png";

    $x = 0 ;
    while (file_exists($path))
    {
        $path = $picOne ."-" . $x . ."_170x170.png"; 
        $x++;
    }
```

This would always give you a new file name all the time and you can put it in a simple function.

Comment: It's not overwriting an existing file. It just creates a new file called name.png_170x170.png and adds that to $picOne as well. I don't want $picOne as _170x170.png, only as name.png